# Typescript number or object. Property on object doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, apexcharts

I'm trying to understand why this is invalid but googling hasn't lead me to any answers so I'm hoping somebody can point me in the right direction here.

```
const latestTotal: number | {
    x: any;
    y: any;
    fillColor?: string | undefined;
    strokeColor?: string | undefined;
    meta?: any;
    goals?: any;
} | [number, number | null] | [number, (number | null)[]] | null | undefined

console.log(latestTotal.y)
// Property 'y' does not exist on type 'number | { x: any; y: any; fillColor?: string | undefined; strokeColor?: string | undefined; meta?: any; goals?: any; } | [number, number | null] | [number, (number | null)[]]'. Property 'y' does not exist on type 'number'
```

Shouldn't it look at the object definition instead of the number definition? This def is from a library so I can't change it. Can anybody paint me a picture here?

Comment: It's much cleaner and more straightforward to use only one data-type per variable in Typescript.  While it is possible to use multiple via unions, it's just not worth the trouble in my opinion.

Comment: @TobiasS. Yes this is what I was looking for! Thank you. If const is typeof object && y in obj satisfies the error.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `number | {...}` means that the variable can be both number or object and as .y does not exist on number you are getting this error.

This behavior is explained here in official documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

This applied to your example means something like this:

```js
// I have made interface from that object
interface chart {
  x: any;
  y: any;
  fillColor?: string | undefined;
  strokeColor?: string | undefined;
  meta?: any;
  goals?: any;
}
// You were using ":" to give variable a value. : Is used to give it type
var latestTotal: number | chart | [number, number | null] |[number, (number | null)[]] | null | undefined = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}

if (typeof latestTotal === "object") {
  console.log(latestTotal.y)
}
```

I also had to change your `const` to a `var` because if it was as a `const`and you changed the value to anything but that object, you would be getting another error saying:

> Property 'y' does not exist on type 'never'

because `const` is immutable and if set to number it won't ever become an object.

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring variable as a `const` so it expects you to provide some value to it. If you declare it as `let` even then you have to define some value to it before accessing it(using console log). Once you define the value then only you can access the variable based on its definition.

**Compiler error:**
[image: wrong way]

**Correct Way**
[image: correct way]